# Unable to compile Ultralite library for Iphone for my Xcode 4.3.3

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, xcode4.3, sybase

I am new to iphone development . In my application I am trying to provide Ultralite Sync

mechanism. I am  referring the following link:

http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/ulc/compile-iphone-library.html.

But when I try to Compile the library for the iPhone simulator , I get the error. That is,

when I  execute the ./build.sh  command. I get the following error

make: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory

I assume, I am getting error because Developer folder is missing as I am using XCode

version 4.3.3. I am really banging my head to get the solution. Can any one help me out,

please ?

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this error as well and got past it by doing the following:

1)Launch XCode
2)Click XCode...Preferences menu
3)Click on Locations
4)Select the 'Command Line tools' drop down and select the version number.

Mine was unseleced. After making this selection and rerunning the command line tools I was able to get past this error. (Although now I have other errors in the script)

Comment: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer: is a directory . This is the Error I get when I tried to execute ./build.sh in the terminal